# Decrease execution time of "firstDuplicate" algorithm

Tags: javascript

```
function firstDuplicate(a) {
  var numbers = {},
      res;

foo:
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (a[i] === a[j]) {
        numbers[a[i]] = j - i;
        if (j - i === 1 ) {
            break foo;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var keys = Object.keys(numbers),
      res = keys[0];

  keys.forEach(function (v) {
    res = numbers[res] > numbers[v] ? v : res;
  });

  console.log(res);

  return res === undefined ? -1 : Number(res);
}
```

This function returns the first duplicate value in the array of numbers.

I want to decrease its execution time. What changes should I do?

## Examples

1. For `a = [2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]`, the output should be `firstDuplicate(a) = 3`.

There are 2 duplicates: numbers `2` and `3`. The second occurrence of `3` has a smaller index than the second occurrence of `2` does, so the answer is `3`.

2. For `a = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1]`, the output should be `firstDuplicate(a) = -1`.

Comment: This functions definitely doesn't return "the first duplicate in the array". What do you really want to do?

Comment: @JakubDąbek I think he wants to return index of the first duplicate

Comment: I think OP wants an index where the next duplicate comes as soon as possible. But I think it fails, because `numbers[a[i]]` gets overridden so that it only looks at the last pair of duplicates for each value of `a[i]`. So if `a = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a']`, then it will find the (1,3) pair instead of the (0,1) pair. But yes, this definitely needs more clarity.

Comment: @GaneshSundaram you want "the first duplicate value in the array of numbers". So if `a = [4, 4, 9, 9]` you want to return `4`. What if `a = [4, 9, 9, 4]`?

Comment: Why do you convert your value to a number if you don't look for an index?

Comment: @DavidKnipe for a = [4, 9, 9, 4] answer 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array contains number or string you can do something like this,

```js
//Returns the first duplicate element   
function firstDup(arr) {
  let o = {}; //an empty object
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (o[arr[i]]) { //check if the property exists
      return arr[i];
    } else {
      o[arr[i]] = 'a'; //set the object's property to something non falsy
    }
  }
  return -1; //If No duplicate found return -1
}

console.log(firstDup([2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]));
console.log(firstDup([2, 4, 3, 5, 1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function firstDuplicate(array) {
  const numbers = {};
  
  for (const number of array) {
    if (numbers[number]) {
      return number;
    } else {
      numbers[number] = true;
    }
  }
  
  return -1; // No duplicate
}

const duplicate = firstDuplicate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 1, 3]);
console.log(duplicate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may instead use `find` and `indexOf` :

```
 function findFirstDupe(array) {
   return array.find((n, i) => array.indexOf(n) !== i);
 }
```

Or you use a Set to check for previous appearances:

```
function findFirstDupe(array){
  const set = new Set();
  return array.find(n => set.has(n) || (set.add(n), false));
}
```

The same with an object as a hash:

```
function findFirstDupe(array){
  const hash = {};
  return array.find(n => !(hash[n] = !hash[n]))
}
```